# Are semicolons required in Java?

Tags: java, syntax

A basic part of Java syntax (as well as that of most C-based languages) is that semicolons are required at the end of every statement.

However, I managed to write the following program, without using any semicolons:

```
class Hello extends Exception
{
    Hello(String s)
    {
        super(s)
    }
}

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Hello
    {
        world((char)130)
    }

    static void world(char c) throws Hello
    {
        throw new Hello(new String(new char[]{c}))
    }
}
```

Running NetBeans 7.4, it warned me about the lack of semicolons, but it did work properly. However, when I [posted this on CodeGolf.SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/23233), others commented that it didn't work with `javac` or the Eclipse IDE. So, are semicolons required, or not?

Comment: Some compilers will accept this with a warning because there is no two-statement methods to cause errors. This is syntactically incorrect and will not compile with `javac` like the CodeGolfers said

Comment: If what you say is true, I consider this a bug in NetBeans.

Answer (score 7):

Mostly yes, semicolons are required.

When exactly they are required can be found in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/). For example (from [chapter 14](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html)):

**14.4. Local Variable Declaration Statements**

```
LocalVariableDeclarationStatement:
    LocalVariableDeclaration ;
```

**14.6. The Empty Statement**

```
EmptyStatement:
    ;
```

**14.8. Expression Statements**

```
ExpressionStatement:
    StatementExpression ;
```

**14.10. The assert Statement**

```
AssertStatement:
    assert Expression1 ;
    assert Expression1 : Expression2 ;
```

**14.13. The do Statement**

```
DoStatement:
    do Statement while ( Expression ) ;
```

And so on and so on. As you can see the semicolons are actually right there in the spec, as literal text. I find these language specs always a bit funky to read but basically they are defining the syntax from small, sort-of atomic concepts such as 'EmptyStatement', keywords and literal text, up to the higher level structures such as do-while, if-then-else etc. So if you want to know exactly when you need a semicolon or not, study the spec carefully.

Answer (score 3):

Netbeans is most likely inferring the semicolons because you only have one statement in each block.  It is adding them behind the scenes before compiling it.

Semicolons are required for Java because they're part of the spec.

Comment: After almost 10 years from this, isn't that getting changed now? (thinking)

Answer (score 0):

of course they are required. Try adding the semicolons and check if it will work with javac or Eclipse IDE. In Eclipse it won't let run the code if it doesn't contain semicolons.